# Why does my gitlab pipeline fail with rsync error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I used the pipeline in a another project and here it worked.
But now I have a problem (I'm using exactly the same settings)

```
staging_upload:
  stage: staging
  only:
    refs:
      - develop
      - schedules
  script:
    - sshpass -e rsync -avz --progress --exclude='.git' --exclude='.gitlab-ci.yml' . $SSH_USERNAME@j$HOST:/home/xy/html/project/staging/
```

Now I get this error:

```
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(644) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Has anyone a clue what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`sshpass` is very [rarely used](https://github.com/search?q=gitlab-ci%20rsync%20sshpass%20extension%3Ayml&type=Code) in `gitlab-ci.yml` files.
[Much more frequent](https://github.com/search?q=gitlab-ci%20rsync%20ssh%20%20extension%3Ayml&type=Code) is the use of an ssh-agent (if your private key is passphrase-protected), [as seen here](https://github.com/gwynethbradbury/itdatasurvey/blob/e71b3e2009881e86c421542f8d05c4f3e95fd54f/app/auth/.gitlab-ci.yml#L1-L8).

```
before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - 'which rsync || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install rsync -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV")
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PROD")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo "$SSH_HOSTKEYS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts'

dev:
  script:
    - rsync --exclude=.gitlab-ci.yml --exclude=.git -avx -e ssh `pwd`/ dbasdev@iaas.ouce.ox.ac.uk:/var/www/html/it_dev/it_monitor_app/auth/
```

Check if this approach is more reliable, using a [masked variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#masked-variables) for your private key.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script with a -v (or 2). The verbose output will show you where/why it is stalling. Also, validate your escaped characters and absolute paths. They are fairly common reasons for rsync to stall.